# Boolean indexing with 2D arrays

Tags: numpy, numpy-indexing

I have two arrays, `a` and `b`, one 2D and one 1D, containing values of two related quantities that are filled in the same order, such that `a[0]` is related to `b[0]` and so on.

I would like to access the element of `b` where `a` is equal to a given value, where the value is a 1D array itself.

For example

```
a=np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
b=np.array([0, 7, 9, 4])

value = np.array([0,1])
```

In 1D cases I could use boolean indexing easily and do

```
b[a==value]
```

The result I want is `7`.

But in this case, it does not work because it checks each element of `b` in the comparison, instead of checking subarrays...

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't seem to match the example, but this returns `[7]`:

```
b[(a == value).all(axis=-1)]
```

Comment: @etien well that's the thing, the `7` comes from `b` not from `a`. Maybe in your example the 1D array should be called `a` and the 2D should be `b` ?

Comment: Ah sorry, i think i understand now: i inverted `a` and `b` when i wrote the example for the 1D case (and i accidentally also deleted my previous comment) I will edit the question now accordingly!